# Remotely deploying a web application (.war)

Tags: servlets, jetty

I have a java server (jetty) running on a remote machine. Currently I'm manually copying a .war file from my local dev machine to the remote machine whenever I need to put up an update. This is a really slow dev cycle.

Jetty will restart a web application if you stick a new .war file in its /webapps folder.

I could add a new servlet which accepts a .war upload, and sticks it in its own /webapps folder - thus overwriting and restarting itself? Then whenever I need to redeploy, I just upload the .war file from my local machine to the running instance on the remote machine. Sounds pretty wonky. Any better ways of doing something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you copying it, FTP?

Generally you should spend a good amount of intial time working on automating your deployments - upfront time spent now will be hours saved later.  I like to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), but if you've got a simple situation and don't want as steep of a learning curve, [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) is a good start.

(edit) Maybe [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container).

Comment: Ha my setup is currently awful. I copy the .war file from my local machine to a Temp remote ftp site. I log into the remote prod machine with VNC. From that machine I download from the remote ftp site. Move the .war into the /webapps folder. Restart jetty. Takes a really long time.